# Why does vsql can return all the records, while program using ODBC driver can't?

Tags: odbc, vertica, unixodbc, dbvisualizer

I do a simple test for `Vertica`:

```
ha=> insert into test(Name, City) values( 'Nan', 'Nanjing');
 OUTPUT 
--------
      1
(1 row)

ha=> select node_name, wos_row_count, ros_row_count from projection_storage where anchor_table_name = 'test';
   node_name   | wos_row_count | ros_row_count 
---------------+---------------+---------------
 v_ha_node0001 |             1 |             3
(1 row)

ha=> select * from test;
   ID   | Name |  City   
--------+------+---------
 250001 | Nan  | Nanjing
 250002 | Nan  | Nanjing
 250003 | Nan  | Nanjing
 250004 | Nan  | Nanjing
(4 rows)
```

The `select` operation displays OK (the data in `WOS` and `ROS`all display).

Then I write a simple program which uses `ODBC`:

```
ret = SQLExecDirect(stmt_handle, (SQLCHAR*)"select * from test", SQL_NTS);
if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret))
{
    printf("Execute statement failed\n");
    goto ERR;
}

while ((ret = SQLFetch(stmt_handle)) == SQL_SUCCESS)
{
    row_num++;
}

printf("Row number is %d\n", row_num);
```

But the result is:

```
Row number is 3
```

It doesn't count the data in `WOS`.

And the `DbVisualizer` also displays 3 rows of data:
[image: VXTML]

Does it need some special option for using `ODBC`? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Have you committed the transaction?

Comment: @Kermit: I don't use transaction. I can see the data from `vsql` client.

Comment: @NanXiao Transactions are on by default. Within vsql, as long as you do not quit your session you will be inside the default transaction and will see your just inserted data. As a very easy confirmation (or infirmation), do the same as in your question, but type 'COMMIT;' in vsql *before* running your odbc or dbvis test. Then we can rule out transactions for sure.

Comment: @Guillaume:Oh, yes. After using 'COMMIT;' in vsql, both my odbc and dbvis can see the data. So it seems my vsql don't commit transaction by default. How can I check whether vsql enable `commit transaction by default` or not? After using `\h` command, I can't find some information. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, vsql is in transaction mode. As long as you keep your session open, **inside** vsql, you will see what you expect, as you are inside a transaction.

As soon as you go **outside** of your session (odbc, dbvis), the transaction is not (yet) visible. To make it visible to other sessions, you need to issue a 'COMMIT;' inside vsql. Then (as confirmed) you can access data from odbc and dbvis.

You can set (vsql only) your transaction to be [autocommit](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ProgrammersGuide/vsql/AUTOCOMMIT.htm) with

```
\set AUTOCOMMIT on
-- disable with
\set AUTOCOMMIT off
```

To know if autocommit is enabled, you can use [show](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/SHOW.htm):

```
show AUTOCOMMIT;
    name    | setting
------------+---------
 autocommit | off
(1 row)
```

You can even do it on your [vsql](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ProgrammersGuide/vsql/CommandLineOptions.htm) call with `--set autocommit=on`. Is that a good idea or not is another question.

ODBC lets you set autocommit in different ways, see the [odbc doc](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ProgrammersGuide/ClientODBC/DSNParameters.htm).

Comment: I'm still asleep while you're answering Vertica questions.

Comment: @kermit I have noticed it the other way round as well :)